# how do i get data from SQLite3 table as a float? it is being returned as a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

This is the test code,

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('locations.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT Latitude FROM adress")

result= cur.fetchone()

print(type(result))
```

and then it prints out

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

I have 5 columns in that database and one of them is `latitude`, I'd like to return it as a float but it comes as a tuple. Hence I can't use it for what I need it for! How can I make a float out of it?

Comment: i read somewhere that using `fetchone()` is the reason why it returns a tuple, what are the other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchone()` always returns a tuple. If you select one column, it will return a 1-dimension tuple.

The solution is simple, just go and use the first element of the tuple.

`result= cur.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: Side note: if you really need to *ensure* it's a float, you know you can explicitly convert it: `result = float(cur.fetchone()[0])`

Comment: just one more issue, in the future i might need to get more than one longitude, how do i do that?

Comment: Do you mean *more than one latitude*? `cur.fetchall()` gives you a list of tuples. So iterate over the list and use the first element of each tuple. If you mean there's another column named *longitude*, query `SELECT latitude, longitude FROM your-table-name`, and `fetchone()` will return a 2-D tuple (latitude, longitude).

Comment: now, if i use `fetchall(0)` it returns a list ... i'm thinking maybe i can use a for loop